# How do I send objdump result to a file?

Tags: c++, c, windows, objdump

I want to run objdump on an execuatble file in windows XP, and want to observe the details. However, I am unable to find option to output the result in a text file - since the output display in console is chopped off
(I also tried using the options -o or /out to specify ooutfilename, but do not seem to exist)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Doesn't the shell's normal output redirection work for you?  Example:

```
objdump -d file.o > file.txt
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the tip, i thought earlier that it worked only on unix